# Unix/C command line arguments: Every single function has the same error what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, unix, command-line, argv, argc

I am supposed to take in arguments from the command line, to build a sample Unix-style 'ls' style program that lists the directory contents.

I have pre-built functions given to me and I have to separate the code down into modularized header and c files for each individual function and create a makefile.

The makefile will run and gives these warnings:

```
-bash-3.2$ make run
gcc -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘do_ls’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Here is do_ls.h:

'''

```
#ifndef DO_LS
#define DO_LS
                void do_ls( char*[] );


#endif
```

'''

Errors:

```
-bash-3.2$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘do_ls’ from incompatible pointer type
main.c:23: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘do_ls’ from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/cc8Q7153.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `do_ls'
main.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `do_ls'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main:

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <sys/types.h>
#include        <dirent.h>
#include        "do_ls.h"


    int main(int ac, char *av[])
    {
     if ( ac == 1 )
            do_ls(".");

     else
            while ( --ac ){
                    printf("%s:\n", *++av );
                    do_ls( *av );
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code from `do_ls.h`.

Comment: If you invoke `gcc` without any command-line flags, it tries to produce an executable. It can't do that unless: (1) `main()` is defined, and (2) every function you use is defined (not just declared). That's what those linker errors are trying to tell you. That has nothing to do with your segfault, although the incorrect parameter type warning in your first compilation is probably relevant.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  What you've provided is not an MCVE — we need to see `do_ls.h` and we don't need to know about the existence of `dostat.h`, `show_file_info.h`, `mode_to_letters.h`, `uid_to_name.h` or `gid_to_name.h` (and you don't need any of the system headers except `<stdio.h>` for the `main()` function you show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do_ls` function expects an array of `char *`, but when you call it you only pass in a single `char *`.  This is what the warning in the initial call to `make` is complaining about.  This argument mismatch invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Try calling it like this:

```
if ( ac == 1 ) {
    char *args[] = { ".", NULL };
    do_ls(args);
} else {
    do_ls(av+1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Initially doing this I am still getting an incompatible pointer type. will I have to redefine the header and function prototype if I do this for do_ls.h?

Comment: @amorphous_solid Presumably, `do_ls` was given to you so you shouldn't change it.  Instead, you need to make sure what you pass in matches what it expects.

Comment: I will say it is now compiling and outputting the correct things with this fix regardless of the incompatible pointer type error. Thank you